# Youtube - How to browse all channels in a given category?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

For example, there are 884 channels under beauty and fashion, however, Youtube only shows about 50 of them. How do i get the complete list? Either through API or web.

https://www.youtube.com/channels/beauty_fashion

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to do is to get the Guide Category ID that you're interested in. If you do a call to

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/guideCategories?part=snippet&hl=en&regionCode=US&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

where the hl parameter is the language and the regionCode is the country code (as some categories may not be available for particular languages/regions), you'll get a list of all the categories and their IDs.

For example, that call tells us that the Beauty and Fashion guide category ID is GCQmVhdXR5ICYgRmFzaGlvbg. With that ID, we can then do a channels list call:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&maxResults=50&categoryId=GCQmVhdXR5ICYgRmFzaGlvbg&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

This will give you 50 channels in that category. It will also give you a 'nextPageToken' ... you do the same request as above, but add "&pageToken={WHATEVER THAT NEXT PAGE TOKEN VALUE IS}" to get the next 50, and so on.

You can retrieve up to 500 that way ... that's the limit through the API.

Note that all of these calls require an API key from console.developers.google.com

Comment: Now I am getting item[] is blank in above API from last couple of days,Please check below response
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/E0c9LqWjuNHvL-UjCIKS4N9Fn5M\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },
 "items": []
}

Can you please help me for that... Any idea how to resolve that...

Answer (score 1):

Visit this site: http://www.channelcrawler.com/

You can list the channel in selected category and many other options.