# How to get YouTube PlayLists by Category e.g Education, Sports, etc

Tags: api, google-api, youtube, youtube-data-api, playlist

Is there any way where I can get youtube playlists by category only as I have created search button in my app and I dont want to render random playlists from youtube..

p.s.I couldnt find anything on google data api

I think it (videoCategory) is only available for videos search, not for playList... which I applied successfully.

Comment: Can you get such playlists from [YouTube UI](https://www.youtube.com)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know YouTube playlists haven't a category assigned. However you can filter [channels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30385365) and [videos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54908961) per category. Nevertheless note that you can't list all YouTube playlists containing a given video.